# Comparar string opcional con EditText swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

Hola con todos muchachos.
Tengo una comparación de dos atributos (string?) con sus respectivos textos ingresados. Los atributos son los siguientes

```
class Usuario: NSObject {

    var id:Int = Int()
    var idPrivilegio:Int = Int()
    var correo:String?
    var clave:String?

func buscar(incluirInactivo: Bool)-> NSMutableArray
    {
        conexion.database!.open()

        var stringConsulta = "select * from USUARIO"
        let consulta: FMResultSet! = conexion.database!.executeQuery(stringConsulta, withArgumentsIn: nil)
        let listaUsuarios: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        if (consulta != nil)
        {
            while consulta.next(){
                let itemUsuario: Usuario = Usuario()
                itemUsuario.id = Int(consulta.int(forColumn: "CODIGOUSUARIO"))
                itemUsuario.idPrivilegio = Int(consulta.int(forColumn: "CODIGOPRIVILEGIO"))
                itemUsuario.correo = consulta.string(forColumn: "CORREOUSUARIO")
                itemUsuario.clave = consulta.string(forColumn: "CLAVEUSUARIO")
                listaUsuarios.add(itemUsuario)
            }
        }
        conexion.database!.close()
        return listaUsuarios
    }

    func insertar(itemUsuario: Usuario) ->Bool
    {
        conexion.database!.open()
        let consulta: Bool = conexion.database!.executeUpdate("insert into USUARIO (CODIGOPRIVILEGIO,CORREOUSUARIO,CLAVEUSUARIO) values (\(itemUsuario.idPrivilegio),'\(String(describing: itemUsuario.correo))','\(String(describing: itemUsuario.clave))'", withArgumentsIn: nil)
        conexion.database!.close()
        let aux = !consulta ?  false : true
        return aux
    }
}
```

La comparación la hago con esta linea

```
if(usuario.correo! == txtCorreo.text && usuario.clave! == txtPassword.text){
//codigo
}
```

Pero no me genera la comparación de manera adecuada, en el proceso de debug se muestran las variables de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La comparación siempre me da false. Por favor ayuda con este inconveniente

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu clase `Usuario`? Intuyo que cuando inicializas el email y el pass debe estar construido algo parecido a esto: `self.email = "\(someVar)"` en donde `someVar` será de tipo `String?`. Ver la clase ayudaría.

Comment: Muchas gracias...ya agregué el código solicitado, no tengo un método de inicialización, sino que cargo los usuarios de la base con  los métodos escritos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu función insertar es donde estás teniendo el problema. Dado que `usuario.correo` y `usuario.clave` son **opcionales**, con el método

```
'\(String(describing: itemUsuario.correo))'
```

estás provocando que en la BBDD se inserte el valor `'Optional("una clave")'` literalmente, con el string `Optional` y todo, y por eso luego no te coincide con el valor que introduces, porque realmente son 2 strings diferentes.

Prueba a usar el operador `??` de manera que si existe un valor en `clave`y `correo`, fuerza el `unwrap` para guardarlo en la bbdd, y si no existe, le asigna un valor por defecto (en el ejemplo, un string vacío):

```
func insertar(itemUsuario: Usuario) ->Bool
{
    conexion.database!.open()
    let consulta: Bool = conexion.database!.executeUpdate("insert into USUARIO (CODIGOPRIVILEGIO,CORREOUSUARIO,CLAVEUSUARIO) values (\(itemUsuario.idPrivilegio),'\(String(describing: itemUsuario.correo ?? ""))','\(String(describing: itemUsuario.clave ?? ""))'", withArgumentsIn: nil)
    conexion.database!.close()
    let aux = !consulta ?  false : true
    return aux
}
```

Imagino que tendrás que borrar los usuarios que ya tengas guardados con ese método, para insertar bien los registros.

Comment: Me has hecho el día hombre...muchas gracias, funcionó perfectamente